# Implementing Jest tests on POST services authenticated with auth0

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, auth0

I am trying to implement Jest testing on my node.js server however I am unsure how to test POST services that are secured with auth0 ensureLoggedIn, I simply get a 302 response rather than expected 200 or 400 due to not being able to authenticate.

I tried initially to create an dummy copy of app.js with ensureLoggedIn removed from service declarations however I was told this not correct. I was pointed in the direction of mock functions however I am unsure how to mock up auth0 authentication.

Example app.js

```
app.post('/secure', ensureLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    -Process Request-
    if (Request Bad) {
        return res.sendStatus(400);
    }
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Example test.js

```
describe('Test POST service /secure' () => {
    test('POST /secure with valid body' async() => {
        const update = {Valid JSON body};
        return request(app)
            .post('/secure')
            .send(update)
            .expect(200);
    });
})
```

Right now, I expect this test to fail as it is not being authenticated. My question is, what is the correct way to handle authentication with auth0 when using jest tests?

Thanks.